# switching boolean value in PHP

Tags: php, boolean

Let's say I have the following function which should return `True` if valid and `False` if invalid.

Is there a shortcut to return the 'opposite' of the boolean `$this->errors`?

Should I use a one-line `if statement` or is there another possibilty?

So if `$this->errors` is `false` I want it to return `true` :P

```
function valid() {

    $this->errors = False;

    if ($somethingiswrong) {
        $this->errors = True;
    }

    return $this->errors;
}
```

EDIT

OMG How come I never see the right questions/answers when I use the search option. But find the right answers when I already posted :P

```
return !$this->errors;
```

Is what I was looking for.

Comment: `return $this->errors ? false : true;`  JUST KIDDING don't do this ;)

Comment: `return ($this->errors != false ? false : true)` just to make things even more confusing for the next person to stumble into that code block

Comment: @Byron and Marc: I might just do that just to screw with people ;)

Comment: What the heck it's Friday: `return !!!!!(!!!$this->errors ? !!(boolean)false : !!(boolean)'false');`

Comment: @webbiedave: omg lol you should really stop using meth and/or crack :P

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
return !$this->errors;
```

`!` is [logical negation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Thanks! :D That's it as I also found at the related section. However thanks again!